# mysqlworkbecnh connection to mysql

Tags: mysql-workbench

I could not connect to mysql with my mysqlworkbench.
I am using `mamp` and it gives me the below error:

```
Failed to Connect to MySQL at localhost:8888 with user root
I have put the username "root" and no password.
Hostname:localhost Port:8888
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally we get this issue when the port is used from another app in the background.
So check your running programs or change mamp port itself to anything else like
`port:7001`.

I recommend Xampp if you're using Windows Operating system. It works well on `port:3306`.

Comment: A (deep)link to the docs of MAMP where they explain which ports to use (on Windows): https://documentation.mamp.info/en/MAMP-Windows/Preferences/Ports/